# Ingestion port for seq in serilog

Tags: .net, logging, serilog, seq, seq-logging

I've installed seq on a local server using dockers, here the docker command:

```
docker run -d \
 --restart unless-stopped \
 --name seq \
 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
 -v /var/log/seq:/data \
 -p 8680:80 \
 -p 8631:5431 \
 datalust/seq:latest
```

Then, I configured my project to send Logs to the server using app.config files. File extract here:

```
<!-- log server -->
<add key="serilog:using:Seq" value="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://192.168.1.200:8680" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.apiKey" value="CONFIGURED-API-KEY-HERE" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Debug"/>
```

I couldn't get it to work until I changed server port to 8680. Before I was getting `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused` exception.

The point is, shouldn't I use 8631 port instead of 8680? 8680 port is just for website, 8631 should be ingestion port. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the port mapping:

```
-p 8631:5431
```

The Seq ingestion port is port `5341`, not `5431`, so this needs to be:

```
-p 8631:5341
```

Comment: and the mnemonic for the port is _Seq!_ - 5341 ;)

Comment: It's working now. I have to remove (rm) and rerun docker to make it works. It looks like editing ports is not easy for dockers. Still don't understand why both ports (80 and 5341) work for ingestion.

Comment: 80 is the full API; 5341 is ingestion-only for situations where minimal exposed surface area is desirable. HTH!